# Removing Unwanted Azure AD Directories from my Listing

Tags: azure

My `Azure Subscription` is listing `Default Directories` from other people's subscriptions within my "All Directories" listing.  I want to remove them...but I'm having an EXTREMELY difficult time doing it.

- I have contacted the owners of these directories...and they do not respond to my requests to be removed
- This has been going on for months

Q: How do I dis-associate myself and/or remove these directories from my listing?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Unfortunately, the `"Leave New Experience"` on `https://myapps.microsoft.com` does not display enough information to be sure "which" `Default Organization` I am leaving.

- I could accidentally leave my own...right?
- I took a chance...and it threw an exception...so this UI doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

- Log into the Access Panel at https://myapps.microsoft.com
- In the upper-right corner, select your name.
- Next to Organizations, select the settings icon (gear).
- Under Organizations, find the organization that you want to leave, and select Leave organization.

NOTE : If you are not seeing the gear icons next to organizations, you need to switch to the new old look by clicking on leave new experience as below

[image]

Comment: That's the older My Apps portal, for me it automatically redirects to the new one that doesn't have these features any more :( I found these at myaccount.microsoft.com after some looking.

Comment: Though that said this might actually work with personal accounts (which the newer one seems not to).

Comment: That's correct! You need to manually switch to old look

Comment: SEE 'UPDATES' ABOVE: Thanks for the help...but...unfortunately the UI doesn't show enough information be be able to confidently leave. They all say "Default Directory".    I "could" accidentally leave my own.

Comment: I went ahead & marked this answer as correct...with the caveat...that you could accidentally delete your own "Default Directory" (because the Azure UI is done so poorly)

Answer (score 1):

This works even for personal addresses:

Go to `https://myaccount.microsoft.com?tenantId={directoryId}` (replace `{directoryId}` with guid of the directory you wish to leave), click *Organizations*, click *Leave*, verify that guid is correct and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations to leave AAD organizations that you have been invited to.

Comment: Oddly...that link doesn't work for personal email addresses?  Only organizational ones

Comment: And the account link atop the Azure Portal of... https://account.microsoft.com ...has no such functionality